# How to use more than one DBContext in a controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, dbcontext

How to use more than one DBContext in a controller, I tried to overload the construktors in different ways?

Some Controller:

```
public C1(DBContext1 a, DBContext2 b, DBContext3 c)
{ 
}
 //public C1(DBContext1 a)
 //{ 
 //}
 //public C1(DBContext2 b)
 //{
 //}
 //public C1(DBContext3 c)
 //{
 //}
```

StartUp.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext1>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(new string(K.ConnectionString))
);

services.AddDbContext<DBContext2>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(new string(K.ConnectionString))
);

services.AddDbContext<DBContext3>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(new string(K.ConnectionString))
);
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454436/when-to-use-more-than-one-dbcontext-in-the-entity-framework), but it seems to be outdated

Error(, when Calling the constructor by the frontend):

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> Exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: The DbContextOptions
> passed to the DBContext1 constructor must be a
> DbContextOptions. When registering multiple DbContext
> types make sure that the constructor for each context type has a
> DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic
> DbContextOptions parameter.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions
> options)    at _4_DWH.DBContext1..ctor(DbContextOptions options) in
> D:...\DBContext1.cs:line 43    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
> scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
> serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

DBContext:

```
public class DBContext1 : DbContext
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(new string(sameConnectionString));
    }

    public DBContext1() : base()
    {

    }

    public DBContext1(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937314/registering-multiple-dbcontext-instances-on-startup-for-use-in-generic-repositor helps you ?

Comment: Why does this not work already? Show a screenshot indicating the problem/how you know there is a problem. Show us any code creates the controller (it shouldn't; the DI should do it). Show us the controller DI registration. Show the values of the arguments to the constructor. Tell us any error messages

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291025/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-web-api

Comment: you need to use `DbContextOptions<DbContext1>`, `DbContextOptions<DbContext2>` ... instead of just `DbContextOptions` (in the constructors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create DB contexts

```cs
public class DBContext_A : DbContext
{
    public DBContext_A(DbContextOptions<DBContext_A> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class DBContext_B : DbContext
{
    public DBContext_B(DbContextOptions<DBContext_B> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class DBContext_C : DbContext
{
    public DBContext_C(DbContextOptions<DBContext_C> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

2. Define a connection string for each DBContext:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection_A": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DB_A;Trusted_Connection=True;...",
    "Connection_B": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DB_B;Trusted_Connection=True;...",
    "Connection_C": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DB_C;Trusted_Connection=True;...",
  }
}
```

3. Register in startup:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DBContext_A>(ops =>
{
    ops.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString($"Connection_A"));
});

services.AddDbContext<DBContext_B>(ops =>
{
    ops.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString($"Connection_B"));
});

services.AddDbContext<DBContext_C>(ops =>
{
    ops.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString($"Connection_C"));
});
```

4. Inject into controller:

```cs
public FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly DBContext_A _context_A;
    private readonly DBContext_B _context_B;
    private readonly DBContext_C _context_C;

    public FooController(
            DBContext_A context_A, 
            DBContext_B context_B, 
            DBContext_C context_C)
    {
        _context_A = context_A;
        _context_B = context_B;
        _context_C = context_C;
    }
}
```

#### Additional best-practice for Code First approach:

Create a class library for each context, so when you apply migrations each context will have its own migrations folder in its own project.

- Solution

  - MainProject

    - startup.cs
  - ClassLibrary_A

    - DbContext_A.cs
    - Migrations // folder
  - ClassLibrary_B

    - DbContext_B.cs
    - Migrations // folder
  - ClassLibrary_C

    - DbContext_C.cs
    - Migrations // folder

While applying migrations in a multi context solution;

- From solution explorer, Set the main project (with startup.cs) as "Startup project"
- Set the relevant ClassLibrary_A or B or C from the package manager console as "Default project"
- Add the target context to each cmd as below:

```
PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_A
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_A

PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_B
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_B

PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_C
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_C
```

Alternatively, you may use the full PM cmd as below:

```
PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_A -Project ClassLibrary_A -StartupProject MainProject
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_A -Project ClassLibrary_A -StartupProject MainProject

PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_B -Project ClassLibrary_B -StartupProject MainProject
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_B -Project ClassLibrary_B -StartupProject MainProject

PM > add-migration Init -Context DBContext_C -Project ClassLibrary_C -StartupProject MainProject
PM > update-database -Context DBContext_C -Project ClassLibrary_C -StartupProject MainProject
```