# Is it possible to use database migrations with multiple databases in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have two application settings, one for production and one for development.  I'm also using database migrations to manage my database, that said, with their being two connection strings I can only update the development database from Visual Studio.  My question is, is it possile to run database migrations against two connections strings? i.e. the connections strings I have stored in `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`?

***appsettings.Development.json***

```
{     
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=tcp:devdatabase.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDevelopment;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=whatever;Password=whatever;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***appsettings.Production.json***

```
{     
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProdConnection": "Server=tcp:proddatabase.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyProduction;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=whatever;Password=whatever;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Both my database are stored in Azure, typically if I'm wanting to make changes I'll create a migration in the following manner:

```
Add-Migration AddedBoolColumns
```

Followed by

```
Update-Database
```

The migration takes the development connection string and updates the development database but production remains unchanged and sometimes I want those changed to carry to that database as well.  Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: it would defeat the purpose to update both databases at the same time. the purpose of a development db would be to test it and then update the production db if all is ok

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950778/5519026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the migrations from your local machine you can add the connection string to `Update-Database` as an argument. Example Below.

```
Update-Database -Connection your_connection_string
```

With that said you can run the migrations to as many databases as you want ^^